# Deploy a TFS release to a specific environment using C# and Rest API

Tags: c#, rest, tfs

I'm trying to launch a release to a specific environment using C# and TFS' REST API.

I got the code for executing the request, but I cannot figure out how to organise the parameters for the patch request.

```
public void LaunchRelease(string tfsServerIncludingCollection, string personalAccessToken, string projectName, int releaseId, int environmentId)
{

var releaseUrl = $"{tfsServerIncludingCollection}/{projectName}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}";

var base64Token = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($":{personalAccessToken}"));

var patchDocument = new Object[1];
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64Token);

    var patchValue = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patchDocument), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");

    var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, releaseUrl) { Content = patchValue };
    var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    }
}
```

}

I've seen on the internet, that it should be something like (taken from a different example):

```
patchDocument[0] = new { op = "replace", path = "/relations/attributes/comment", value = "Adding traceability to dependencies" };
```

But I don't know how to combine that with the parameters required by the PATCH operation. Any idea?

Update: By replaying the TFS request on the browser I saw that the API used for internal requests was 3.2-preview.4

By then going in in Postman, I could successfully create the request. I exported the C# content and included it in VS (it uses Restsharp). And it worked.

```
var client = new RestClient("http://MYURL/tfs/MyCollection/MyProj/_apis/Release/releases/3329/environments/11719?api-version=3.2-preview.4");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.PATCH);
request.AddHeader("postman-token", "3f94c3a4-da61-9487-8aeb-7238b4355a77");
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
request.AddHeader("authorization", "Basic MyToken");
request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"status\":2,\"scheduledDeploymentTime\":null,\"comment\":null}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
```

Still, I cannot get the original code to work, even despite making the related changes. Here's the current code

```
public async Task<string> LaunchRelease(string tfsServerIncludingCollection, string personalAccessToken, string projectName, int releaseId, int environmentId)
{

    //Create the URI with the environment to deploy to:
    var releaseUrl = $"{tfsServerIncludingCollection}/{projectName}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}?api-version=3.2-preview.4";

    //Create the patch Document
    var patchDocument = new
    {
        status = 2, 
    };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patchDocument);
    var patchContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var base64Token = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($":{personalAccessToken}"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64Token);

        var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, releaseUrl) { Content = patchContent };
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I could use RestSharp, but I would like to know why it works in one case and not the other.

Comment: I'll see if I can match the rest client code.

Comment: Looks like you just needed to update the api version and the content type of the patch to appllication/json.

Comment: The missing bit was the content type to application/json and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. I updated the answer to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The assumption here is that `environmentId` is the environment to deploy to.

I followed the article here,

Reference [VSTS/TFS REST API: The basics and working with builds and releases](https://www.nwcadence.com/blog/vststfs-rest-api-the-basics-and-working-with-builds-and-releases)

which used PowerShell to perform the API request.

I just adapted it to the code you already provided.

```
public async Task LaunchRelease(string tfsServerIncludingCollection, string personalAccessToken, string projectName, int releaseId, int environmentId) {

    //Create the URI with the environment to deploy to:
    var releaseUrl = $"{tfsServerIncludingCollection}/{projectName}/_apis/release/releases/{releaseId}/environments/{environmentId}?api-version=3.2-preview.4";

    //Create the patch Document
    var patchDocument = new {
        status = 2
    };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(patchDocument);
    var patchContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
        var base64Token = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($":{personalAccessToken}"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", base64Token);

        var method = new HttpMethod("PATCH");
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(method, releaseUrl) { Content = patchContent };
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            //...
        }else {
            var error = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Take note from the article

> If you have pre-deployment approvals before the environment that you deploy to that hasn’t yet been approved, you will need to call that PATCH request before this.

I also checked the official docs to confirm the expected parameters in the request body.

Reference [Releases - Update Release Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update%20release%20environment?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1)

Comment: This did not work. First I saw that the URL needs the version at the end ?api-version=3.0-preview.2 (cause the error message was saying so). Then, after adding it, the result is a failure with Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details.

Comment: @MaPi what version of the API are you using? And what is the exception being thrown?

Comment: I'm on VS 2015. If I use the API version 2.0, 2.1 or 2.2 I get a NotFound. With 2.3 I get a bad request. With 3.0-preview.2 it's an internal server error. There doesn't seem to be additional info on the answer

Comment: @MaPi Check to see if there is content in the response when it fails.

Comment: @MaPi also note this mapping table https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-4.1#api-and-tfs-version-mapping

Comment: It contains the message from before Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response' property of this exception for details. But there is no exception in the response